# React create app proxy agent in package.json is slow on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, package.json, http-proxy

We have proxy defined in `package.json` in our react application (created as create-react-app. We use proxy between front-end (webpack) and back-end (express) during development as [described here](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/06/react-web-express-api-development-production/). Here is the part where we define proxy to the backend server ( `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
}
```

On the backend side (server runs on port `3001`) we call another APIs (but I think it's not important just a note). 
I have noticed that proxy calls from webpack (create-react-app) to express (backed) are really slow. (Windows OS)

```
GET http://localhost:3000/endpoint/ -> ~600ms - 900ms
GET http://localhost:3001/endpoint/ -> ~150ms - 250ms
```

As you can see the time differences between proxy calls (port 3000) and direct calls - port (3001) - are really huge. I expected delay but this looks weird.

Also **sometimes large JSON response (`~38KB`) from proxy is broken** (invalid - e.g missing some parts of a response or swapped characters - in `30%+` cases). I have been struggling with the same issue on backend side and *I think I have resolved it with proxy-agent where I set `keep-alive` connection.*

**Do you have any idea why or how to improve proxy time and behavior?**

Also I tried to set agent in `package.json` but without success.
[create react app documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#configuring-the-proxy-manually)  says:

> You may also specify any configuration value http-proxy-middleware or http-proxy supports.

And [http-proxy documentation](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#options) says

> agent: object to be passed to http(s).request (see Node's https agent
>   and http agent objects)

**Is it possible to define agent in `package.json`?**

I tried but I got following error

> TypeError: Agent option must be an Agent-like object, undefined, or
>   false.
>       at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:106:11)

```
"proxy": {
    "/": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3001",
      "agent": { "keepAlive": true }
    }
  }
```

Highly appreciate any suggestion or idea.

Comment: I do sometimes use the proxy but i never had any issue with it , i think it something related to your OS

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif thanks. Did you notice a delay or higher time differences between proxy and direct calls? And what OS do you use?

Comment: @VladoDemack , a small delay  around 35-40ms but never over 80ms , I use Fedora 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding answer for my question in case somebody has the same issue as we had.

We are forced to use [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) for custom agent. It's sad that we were not able to set our custom agent for `devServer` proxy.

If you need to change agent for devServer it's really nice explained in [documentation](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#extended-configuration-options).

```
// config-overrides.js
module.exports = {
  devServer: function(configFunction) {
    return function(proxy, allowedHost) {
      const config = configFunction(proxy, allowedHost);
      config.proxy.forEach(p => {
        p.agent = agent;
      });
      return config;
    };
  }
}
```

I guess it's workaround and potentially not supported in a future releases of  `create-react-app` **but response time is around 150ms - 230ms** (AND! without invalid JSONs) and it's the thing that counts right now. .

Disturbing note from `react-app-rewired` I would like to point out:

> By doing this **you're breaking the "[guarantees](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/99#issuecomment-234657710)" that CRA provides**. That is to say you now "own" the configs. No support will be provided. Proceed with caution.

I have reported [issue so further investigation will be there.](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4086)